# Equivalent of Ruby Hash in Java

Tags: java, ruby, hash

I am really used at the following kind of code in Ruby:

```
my_hash = {}

my_hash['test'] = 1
```

What is the correspondent data structure in Java?

Comment: A `Map`. The implementation I use is a `HashMap`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("test", 1);
```

I assume?

Comment: It's also worth considering a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) if you want to be able to iterate over your elements in insertion order.

Answer (score 4):

In Java, there are many classes that implement the [`Map<K,V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface, which is what a Ruby "hash" is (the data structure is also commonly known as a "dictionary", or by its full name, a "hashtable"). So in Java, you can either declare an instance of the interface and assign a concrete class to it, or you can declare the concrete instance directly:

```
Map<String, String> definitions = new HashMap<String, String>();
definitions.put("dog", "a four-legged mammal that is Man's best friend");
definition = definitions.get("dog");

TreeMap<Integer, String> players = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
players.put(10, "John Doe");
player = players.get(10);
```

This is somewhat similar to "duck-typing" in Ruby, where if an object responds to a method call `X()`, then Ruby doesn't actually care what type of object that it's calling `X()` on.

The following is the list of some of the classes that implement the `Map<K,V>` interface:

1. [AbstractMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html)
2. [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)
3. [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html)
4. [EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html)
5. [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)
6. [Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)
7. [IdentityHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html)
8. [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)
9. [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)
10. [WeakHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html)

Comment: You can't have generics of a primitive type. `TreeMap<int, String>` won't compile.